# A question about Flasque Sheaves on a site..

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

We define a Flasque Sheaf on a site as one whose first Čech Cohomology vanishes for every covering of every object of the site. I know this definition is non-standard, but Lei Fu's 'Étale Cohomology Theory' uses this definition and shows it to be equivalent to the standard one (i.e, that all higher cohomology groups vanish for every object).

In the proof, he uses the following Lemma which I could not prove: If $$0\rightarrow F'\rightarrow F\rightarrow F''\rightarrow 0$$ is an exact sequence and $F'$ and $F$ are Flasque, so is $F''$. I am not entirely sure if this is true or if Fu has made a mistake, because I have never seen this claim made anywhere else.

Here is the relevant section in the book:

[image]

Comment: An acyclic object in an abelian category is an object such that all its higher cohomology (with respect to some fixed left exact functor) vanishes. By considering the long exact sequence in cohomology it is clear that in a short exact sequence where the first and last terms are acyclic, the middle term is also acyclic. So the claim seems reasonable to me, but the problem is that it is being used to prove that flasque = acyclic...

Comment: To clarify, I'll add the relevant section.

Comment: Hmmm, I misread the claim. If the first and second terms of a short exact sequence are acyclic, then the third term is also acyclic – this is also true but the obvious proof requires you to know that $H^{n+1}$ of the first term and $H^n$ of the second term vanish to conclude that $H^n$ of the third term also vanishes. Maybe it is a typo. I suggest you see where in the later proof you need this fact.

Comment: This fact is used in the following way to prove that the higher Cohomology Groups vanish for a Flasque Sheaf: Take an injective resolution, split it up into short exact sequences, use the fact that Injectives are Flasque and the statement in the question to conclude that the terms in the short exact sequences are Flasque. Hence, taking sections leaves them exact. So, taking global sections leaves the injective resolution exact and the higher Cohomology Groups vanish.

Comment: I keep running into circles trying to prove that $\check{H}{}^1 = 0$ implies $\check{H}{}^n = 0$ for all $n > 0$, so I am starting to suspect the claim is mistaken, or at least is not pure abstract nonsense. Specifically, I don't see how to prove that $\check{H}{}^1 = 0$ implies $\check{H}{}^2 = 0$ – if we assume this then we have the base case for an abstract nonsense inductive argument.

Comment: Yes, I too had the same problem. I supppose one has to use the fact that the first cech cohomology vanishes for ALL objects and ALL covers. I tried to prove it by trying to express the second cohomology groups in terms of the first cohomology groups of the objects in the cover, but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps you might ask on MathOverflow whether this definition is known to be equivalent to the standard one.